# How to install packages from s3 while running a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, package, installation

I have to run a program on lambda that uses packages that exceed the 250 mb size of lambda. I am thinking of installing the required packages from an S3 bucket whenever needed in my code. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, It's not a pattern. If you need to use all these libs, use [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) or try to find a smaller lib.

Comment: Thanks, but I am new to AWS and whenever I log into the AWS console, I am not able to find this service, instead I am shown a page containing options to explore ECS and EKS

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj Fargate is in ECS on console